# Expected number of wins until $k$ consecutive wins

Tags: self-study, expected-value, games, runs

We play the game, where probability that you win a game is $p$. You play until you win $k$ consecutive games. What is expected number of games you win? I can compute that expected number of games is $\frac{1-p^k}{p^k}\frac1{1-p}$.

Comment: Show your work, then.

Comment: it can be represented as Markov Chain, where transition probability from $n$ to $n+1$ is $p$ as $k$ is absorbing.

Comment: I see -- the count of wins does not get accumulated that way. You can probably get fairly close by multiplying by $p$, but this may or may not be the right answer. I think you need to read up on rank nonparametric statistics -- what you are describing seems related to run tests (for independence in Bernoulli trials).

Comment: @StasK You are correct: it's not just fairly close, it's the right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The answer is the expected number of games times the expected number of wins per game.**

**It would be reasonable to doubt this result:** sure, it might be close; but couldn't it miss the mark slightly due to the fact that the game ends (by design) with a large streak of wins?  Let's find a rigorous way to address this question.

Because the question is only about the number of wins, *ignore all losses.*  The course of the game amounts to a series of runs of wins.  It ends when a run of $k$ *or more* wins is observed.

**This description is equivalent to the following more general situation.**  Let $f$ give the probabilities of any discrete distribution on the positive integers $\{1,2,3,\ldots\},$ let $X_i \sim_{iid} f,\ i=1, 2, 3, \ldots$ be a sequence of independent random variables with that distribution, define $\tau = \min\{i\mid X_i\ge k\}$ to be the *stopping time* for this process, and set

$$X = \sum_{i=1}^\tau \min(k, X_i) = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{\tau-1} + k.$$

We seek the value of $e = \mathbb{E}(X),$ the total of the $X_i$ until the process is stopped, counting only $k$ for the value of $X_\tau.$

**There is a simple and obvious recursion:** either $X_1 \ge k$ and the game stops or else we win $X_1$ games *and everything starts all over again.*  Writing $\pi_i=f(i)$ for $i=1,2,\ldots, k-1$ and

$$\pi_k = f(k) + f(k+1) + f(k+2) + \cdots = 1 - (\pi_1 + \pi_2 + \cdots + \pi_{k-1})$$

for the chance of $k$ or more runs, we stop the game and collect $k$ more wins with probability $\pi_k$.  Otherwise we collect $i$ wins and restart the game from the beginning with probabilities $\pi_i,\ i=1, 2, \ldots, k-1.$  Equating the expectations gives

$$e = k\pi_k + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \pi_i(i + e).$$

**The unique solution of this linear equation for $e$ is**

$$e = \frac{1}{\pi_k} \sum_{i=1}^k i \pi_i.$$

**In the situation given by the problem,** $\pi_i \propto p^i$ for $i\lt k$ and

$$\pi_k \propto p^k + p^{k+1} + p^{k+2} + \cdots = \frac{p^k}{1-p}.$$

The sum of all $k$ values is $p/(1-p),$ whence

$$\eqalign{
\pi_i &= (1-p)p^{i-1}, & i=1, 2, \ldots, k-1; \\
\pi_k &= p^{k-1}.&
}$$

This implies

$$e = p^{1-k} \frac{1-p^k}{1-p},$$

exactly $p$ times the expected number of games.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that it is the win probability $p$ times the expected number of games is a simple application of the [optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem)

Let

- $X_n$ be the total number of wins at round $n$. The recentered random variable $Y_n = X_n - p\ n$ is a [martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)).
- $\tau$ be the time till you win $k$ consecutive games. $\tau$ is obviously a [stopping time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time).

You proved that $\mathbb E[\tau]$ is finite, the increments of $Y_n$ are obviously bounded, so the conditions of case (b) of the Wikipedia article of the optional stopping theorem are true. The optional stopping theorem then tells us that:
$$ \mathbb E[Y_\tau] = \mathbb E[Y_0] \\ = 0$$ in our case. And thus:
$$ \mathbb E[X_\tau - p \ \tau] = 0$$
$$ \mathbb E[X_\tau] = p \ \mathbb E[\tau]$$
Just plug-in the expected value of the stopping time you computed, and you have the result.